# How can I prevent my Drawer from rebuilding every time I open it in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter Debug & Profile mode, I have a major performance issue. When I open my drawer, my app drops to about 20 FPS even in profile mode which is unacceptable. I've had issues like this that resolved by themselves in the past because Flutter (on startup) likes to use an old version of my app until I either hot reload or hot restart. But I've tried everything and still, the performance of my app is unacceptable. I just want to prevent my drawer from rebuilding itself every time the user opens it.

**NOTE:** The only time the app works well is in release mode.

CustomDrawer class:

```dart
int _selectedIndex = 0;

class CustomDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  get selectedIndex => _selectedIndex;
  set selectedIndex(int newIndex) => _selectedIndex = newIndex;
  final List<String> appRoutes = App.routes.keys.toList();

  @override
  _CustomDrawerState createState() => _CustomDrawerState();
}

class _CustomDrawerState extends State<CustomDrawer> {
  final List<DrawerItem> _drawerItems = [
    DrawerItem(
      title: "Home",
      icon: OMIcons.home,
    ),
    DrawerItem(
      title: "Assignments",
      icon: OMIcons.assignment,
    ),
    DrawerItem(
      title: "Schedule",
      icon: OMIcons.schedule,
    ),
    DrawerItem(
      title: "Subjects",
      icon: OMIcons.subject,
    ),
    DrawerItem(
      title: "Settings",
      icon: OMIcons.settings,
    ),
    DrawerItem(
      title: "Help and Feedback",
      icon: OMIcons.help,
    ),
    DrawerItem(
      title: "Upgrade",
      icon: OMIcons.star,
      color: Colors.orange,
    ),
  ];
  List<Widget> drawerOptions = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _populateDrawerOptions();
  }

  void _populateDrawerOptions() {
    for (var d in _drawerItems) {
      var i = _drawerItems.indexOf(d);
      drawerOptions.add(CustomListTile(
        icon: d.icon,
        topContainerColor:
            _selectedIndex == i ? Color(0xffe8f0fe) : Colors.transparent,
        iconColor: _selectedIndex == i ? Color(0xff1967d2) : d.color,
        onTap: () => _onSelectItem(i),
        text: d.title,
        textColor: _selectedIndex == i ? Color(0xff1967d2) : d.color,
      ));
    }
  }

  void _onSelectItem(int index) {
    if (_selectedIndex == index) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      return;
    }
    _selectedIndex = index;
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(
      widget.appRoutes[index],
    );
  }

  final Widget drawerHeader = SafeArea(
    top: true,
    child: Container(
      child: Text(
        "School Life",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontFamily: 'OpenSans'),
      ),
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Color drawerColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
    return Drawer(
      child: Container(
        color: drawerColor,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            drawerHeader,
            ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 10),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: drawerOptions,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Any update about it ?